# problem on geometric shapes of space where it is necessary to decide the maximum and minimum value

Tags: calculus, probability, geometry

The points $M$, $N$, $K$ belong respectively to edges $AA_1$, $B_1C_1$, $CD$; cube $ABCDA_1B_1C_1D_1$ with an edge size of $1$. What is the smallest value the sum can acquire

$$MN^2+NK^2+KM^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's make from it a problem of looking for a local minimum of function.
We can make a function of x,y,z such that
$ \\ AM=x, MA1 = 1-x, DM=y, MC=1-y, KB1=z, KC1=1-z \\f(x,y,z)=(1-x)^2+1+z^2 + 1+y^2+x^2+(1-y)^2+1+(1-z)^2\\
$
This lenghts are taken of course from Pythagorean theorem

Then, im too lazy to calculate it bymyself - i used for it Mathematica, we have to count derivative for each variable and solve equation when every of them equals 0.

$
\frac { df}{dx}=4x-2 \\ \frac{df}{dy}=4y-2 \\ \frac{df}{dz}=4z-2
$

After solving these 3 equations you got one solution:
$ x=0.5, y=0.5, z=0.5 $

After counting value of f(x,y,z) you get:
$ f(x,y,z)=3*{\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{9}{2}$

Comment: Quantity to minimize is the sum of squared lengths, square roots are not needed.

Comment: wow, it make it so much easier to calculate

Comment: And one can avoid calculus altogether, by noticing that $x^2+(1-x)^2$ has its minimum at $x=1/2$, and so on.